# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [System.HttpRequest].setHeader(Blob)

Tags: httprequest

I keep getting the following compile error on my HTTP request, Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [System.HttpRequest].setHeader(Blob), Here's my code:

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    req.setMethod('POST' ); // Method Type

    req.setEndpoint('web210.ntree.com/twig-cstc3/v1/login');//salestree url
    Blob LoginBlob = Blob.valueof(loginstring);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setHeader(LoginBlob);

    res = http.send(req);
    if(res.getBody() != null){
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation you will see that the only setHeader method available](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setHeader) has this signature:

```
public Void setHeader(String key, String value)
```

In HTTP, [headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) each have a name and value so you need to supply both.